# Modify column in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

My dataset contains categorical values stored as numbers. Below you can see how is look like my data.

```
data = {'id':['1','2','3','4','5'],
       'nc':['01', '1.0', '2.0', '13.0',"B"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['id','nc'])
```

[image]

Now I want to join this table with a table who have categorical data (e.g 01,02,03 etc.) but I can't because values are not the same.

So can anybody help me how to modify this column or in other words separate values by  **"."** and adding zero for numbers below 10, like the table below:

[image]

I try with this line of code but is not working

```
df["nc1"]= df['nc'].str.split(".", expand = True)
```

Comment: Why does the `1` remains`1`?

Comment: Is not the same. On the first table, you have '1.0' while on the second you have '1'

Comment: Yes, but `2.0` becomes `02`, why does `1.0` remain `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try with [`Series.str.len`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html) and [`Series.str.rstrp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html)

```
df['nc'] = df['nc'].str.rstrip('.0')
df.loc[df['nc'].str.len().le(1) & df['nc'].str.isnumeric(), 'nc'] = '0' + df['nc']
print(df)

  id  nc
0  1  01
1  2  01
2  3  02
3  4  13
4  5   B
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is not fully clear, by changing `2.0` numbers into `02` is quite easy with a regex:

```
df['nc'] = df['nc'].str.replace(r'^(\d+)(\.0+)$', lambda m: m.group(1).zfill(2))
```

output (here as a new column `nc2` for clarity):

```
  id    nc nc2
0  1    01  01
1  2   1.0  01
2  3   2.0  02
3  4  13.0  13
4  5     B   B
```